# Top level function - TypeError: Object(...) is not a function compose

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps, recompose

In my project I am defining a top level Component using [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose)/react-google-maps as follows:

```
const LocationPicker = compose(
    withProps({
        googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,places&key=AIzaSyDnKwHUG_EJXN5EEW6hTftZHYo8E8QTTXY",
        loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
        containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
        mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap,
    withState('places', '', ''),
    withHandlers(() => {
        refs = {
            map: undefined,
        }

        return {
            onMapMounted: () => ref => {
                refs.map = ref
                service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(refs.map.context.__SECRET_MAP_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED);
            },
        }
    }),
)((props) => {
    return (
        <GoogleMap
            ref={props.onMapMounted}
            defaultZoom={13}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: 42.3570637, lng: -71.06257679999999 }}
        >
            {props.marker &&
                <Marker position={{ lat: props.marker.lat, lng: props.marker.lng }} draggable={true} />
            }
        </GoogleMap>
    )
})
```

This iss a Component defined outside the scope of class. I am getting the following error:
`TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`
[image]
Why can't I define the component like this?

Comment: How are you importing the `compose` function? Are you importing it as `import { compose } from 'recompose'`?

Comment: yes - i am importing compose from recompose

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear with my question. Are you wrapping `compose` in curly braces in your import? I'm pretty sure curly braces are required for recompose. It should be `import { compose } from 'recompose'` not `import compose from 'recompose'`. Those are two different imports and I could see getting the error message you posted if the curly braces are missing.

Comment: I imported as I should have using the curly braces(e.g. `import { compose } from 'recompose'`).

Comment: have you tried to remove the functions in `compose` step by step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start I would break this up into a stateless functional component and then enhance the component with Recompose.

```
const LocationPickerView = props => (
  <GoogleMap
    ref={props.onMapMounted}
    defaultZoom={13}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 42.3570637, lng: -71.06257679999999 }}
  >
    {props.marker && (
      <Marker position={{ lat: props.marker.lat, lng: props.marker.lng }} draggable />
    )}
  </GoogleMap>
);

const LocationPicker = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL:
      'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,places&key=AIzaSyDnKwHUG_EJXN5EEW6hTftZHYo8E8QTTXY',
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: '100%' }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: '400px' }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: '100%' }} />
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  withState('places', '', ''),
  withHandlers(() => {
    refs = {
      map: undefined
    };

    return {
      onMapMounted: () => ref => {
        refs.map = ref;
        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(
          refs.map.context.__SECRET_MAP_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED
        );
      }
    };
  })
)(LocationPickerView);
```

I think that will solve your `TypeError`.
If not, try commenting out the `ref` and `withHandler` sections.  You may have a separate issue there.

Comment: Refactored the code and even tried commenting out the `withHandler` snippet  but it's still giving me the same error..`TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`

Comment: What line gives the error now?  What if just try using the `LocationPickerView` directly without the enhancement (probably need to comment out the ref)?